# How to upload videos in Firebase database?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

Can one assist me on how to upload videos in Firebase database...,

```
// Create file metadata including the content type
var metadata = {
    contentType: 'image/jpeg',
};

// Upload the file and metadata
var uploadTask = storageRef.child('images/mountains.jpg').put(file, metadata);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the Realtime Database to store/upload files (I guess your thinking of BLOB/CLOB in RDBMSs when storing large files).

You can either try out uploading it as [a Blob or File](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files#upload_from_a_blob_or_file)

```
var file = ... // use the Blob or File API
ref.put(file).then(function(snapshot) {
    console.log('Uploaded a blob or file!');
});
```

or as a [Byte Array](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files#upload_from_a_byte_array), which are discussed in the documentation

```
// Uint8Array
var bytes = new Uint8Array([0x48, 0x65, 0x6c, 0x6c, 0x6f, 0x2c, 0x20, 0x77, 0x6f, 0x72, 0x6c, 0x64, 0x21]);
ref.put(bytes).then(function(snapshot) {
    console.log('Uploaded an array!');
});
```